# Which of these options are correct?

Tags: real-analysis

For a continuous real function $f$ let $Z(f) = \{x \in R : f(x) = 0 \}$

Then $Z(f)$ is always :

1. compact
2. open
3. connected
4. closed

If I take $f(x) = \sin x$ then $Z(f) = \{n \pi\}$. so it is not bounded and hence not compact. How do i do other options ?

Thanks

Comment: Your example gives almost all what you need. Is $Z(f)$ in your example connected? Is it open?

Comment: i think its not open because we can have a nbd less than size of pi to get empty nbd. is this correct ?

Comment: Well, if you take any open interval around $0$ then it will not contained in $Z(f)$. Hence this set can't be open.

Comment: this is true for every element

Comment: Yes, but to prove a set is not open it's enough to find one point in the set which is not in the interior.

Comment: and how is it not connected

Comment: What definition of connected sets do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Your example already excludes compact, connected and open. As for closed, you can use the following characterisation of continuous functions.

A function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is continuous if and only if the preimage of every closed set is closed.

In this case, $Z(f) = f^{-1}(\{0\})$, and $\{0\}$ is a closed set, so $Z(f)$ is itself closed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a proof $Z$ will be closed, i.e. that $Z^\complement:=\{x\in\Bbb R|f(x)\ne0\}$ is open. If $x\in Z^\complement$, we can construct a neighbourhood $N$ around $x$ with $|f(y)-f(x)|<\delta$ for all $y\in N$, where $\delta$ is your favourite positive real number, e.g. $|f(x)|/2$. This choice ensures $N\subseteq Z^\complement$.

The optins can be excluded by counterexamples, as in the OP & comments.

Comment: Alternatively, $Z(f) = f^{-1}(\{0\})$ which is closed since $f$ is continuous and $\{0\}$ is closed

Answer (score 0):

Consideration of the functions
$$
f(x)=0,\qquad f(x)=x,\qquad f(x)=x^2-1
$$
will lead you to exclude $3$ of the $4$ possibilities.